# How To Configure Chrome Browser To Run In Headless Mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from time import sleep

# Gumtree credentials
username = "my username"
password = "my password"

# Removes SSL Issues With Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('log-level=3') 
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

# Initiate Headless Chrome
#options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
#options.headless = True

# Initiate Chrome Driver
url = 'https://my.gumtree.com/login'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
driver.get(url)

# Find Username/Email Field and Send to Input Field
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(username)
# Find Password Field and Send to Input Field
driver.find_element_by_id("fld-password").send_keys(password)

# Initiate Consent Button
consent_button_xpath = '//*[@id="login-form"]/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/button'
consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, consent_button_xpath)))
consent = driver.find_element_by_xpath(consent_button_xpath)
consent.click()

# Print Username to Test Successful Login
login_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="is-being-refined"]/div[3]/div/header/div[1]/div/nav/div/ul/li[5]/a/div').text
print(login_username)

# close the driver
driver.close()
```

The above script successfully automates the login process into a website using **Selenium** and prints the username.

## Issue

I'm trying to carry out the above in silent mode using **Headless Chrome** without any joy.
I have researched many articles and simply adding the switch **options.add_argument('--headless')** causes the script to fail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

### Error Message

```py
[0830/063818.313:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[0830/063818.313:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python Projects\Gumtree\test5.py", line 39, in <module>
    consent.click()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn-primary btn-full-width" type="submit" data-analytics="gaEvent:...Attempt,userData:{lip:Email}">Login</button> is not clickable at point (386, 564). Other element would receive the click: <button id="onetrust-pc-btn-handler" tabindex="0" class="cookie-setting-link">...</button>
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not using mouse click for the submit button but use the keyboard instead:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
consent.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element Login is not clickable at point (386, 564). Other element would receive the click: ... (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

does not have anything to do with selenium not switching to headless mode.

The moment you write

```
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

and pass this option reference in webdriver object creation call, Selenium will treat this as a headless mode.

1. Also I would suggest to use `explicit waits/Implicit waits`, whenever you think it's required.
2. Headless has never been stable, causing issues here and there. If you just wanna do web **scraping** then consider different tool like `BS4` or request module.
3. Also you should use `relative xpath` rather than *absolute xpath*.